# Add block to sidebar doesn´t work

Tags: category, magento-enterprise, blocks, sidebar

I am having problems adding a block to my sidebar in one of my category pages.
I am using the Custom Layout Update function to add my bestsellers to one specific category page. 
The XML file for my bestsellers is created and the code inside is that one

```
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="bestsellers/view" name="bestsellers.sidebar" before="-" template="bestsellers/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

and then in the Category I have added this

```
 <reference name="left">
    <block type="bestsellers/view" name="bestsellers.sidebar" before="-" template="bestsellers/view.phtml"/>
    <remove name="catalog.leftnav"/>
 </reference>
```

but still it´s nothing showing up there. I am confused why this won´t work. I also thought of adding the block to a static cms block but this won´t work either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: show code?......

Comment: sorry must have been a copy and paste error

Comment: Change name bestsellers.sidebar to  bestsellers.catsidebar.Please show all category.xml code

Comment: I´m confused, why would the name change help so much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For particular category , you can manage it from admin too.From Manage Categories > Your Category > Custom Design > Custom Layout Update

```
<reference name="left">
  <block type="bestsellers/view" name="bestsellers.sidebar" before="-" template="bestsellers/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Comment: thats what I´m doing but nothing is showing up. There is no error, nothing. Maybe the path needs to be relative or anything

Comment: might be this will help         <reference name="left">
          <block type="bestsellers/view" name="bestsellers.sidebar">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>bestsellers/view.phtml</template>
            </action>
          </block>
        </reference>

Comment: this also won´t work. I will try my best and see if I can get it fixed

Answer (score 1):

This is correct

```
 <reference name="left">
    <block type="bestsellers/view" name="bestsellers.sidebar" before="-" template="bestsellers/view.phtml"/>
    <remove name="catalog.leftnav"/>
 </reference>
```

The issue was that I wanted this on my frontpage but it didnt work because the Bestsellers from the root catalog wouldn´t work so after putting it into a category page it worked fine.